# Ugly notation for functions my physics teacher uses: $f(x) = f(x(t)) = f(t)$

Tags: functions, physics, change-of-variable

This is a thing I've often seen, but I don't know whether it has a name and/or a story.

If we have some function $f(x)$, and for some reason $x(t)$ is also a function, they will omit the composition and only write
$f(x) = f(x(t)) = f(t)$

Namely, they don't care about the actual function, but only about what variables it depends onto. This is also used when dealing with derivatives, they will write $$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\, \dot{x}(t)
$$
Does this notation have a name?

Comment: I'm surprised they don't write $\dot{x}$ instead of $x^\prime$.

Comment: Oh they do, I just did not know how to quickly render it on latex

Comment: Fair enough: $\dot{x}$ is `\dot{x}`. Incidentally, `x^\prime` is preferred to `x'`.

Comment: Mixing Leibniz's $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ with Lagrange's $x'$ or with Newton's $\dot{x}$. Newton would be angry either way. The useful notation by Leibniz would be $\frac{d f}{dt}=\frac{d f}{d x}\frac{d x}{dt}$.

Comment: The business of calling $f(x)$ and $f(x(t))$ with the same name is a small abuse of notation that is useful to write less.

Comment: The function $t \mapsto f(x(t))$ is different than the function $f$, so it deserves to have its own name. Unfortunately there’s a common abuse of notation where both functions are called by the same name $f$.